# Bit Field Usage with Union

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to create a simple package with bit fields by using union.
But when I tried to set "bit1" to 1, then all off my bit fields became "1". How can I solve this problem, I want to do that bit field part by using union not by using struct.

So here my struct;

```
    struct {
    union{
        uint8_t bit1 :1 ;
        uint8_t bit2 :1 ;
        uint8_t bit3 :1 ;
        uint8_t bit4 :1 ;
        uint8_t bit5 :1 ;
        uint8_t bit6 :1 ;
        uint8_t bit7 :1 ;
        uint8_t bit8 :1 ;


    }bits;
    uint8_t trial;


    }myStruct_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        myStruct_t.bits.bit1 = 1;
        myStruct_t.bits.bit2 = 0;
        printf("%x",myStruct_t.bits);
        printf("%x",myStruct_t.bits.bit1);
        printf("%x",myStruct_t.bits.bit2);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is: 000.

Comment: That's what a union is. All the members use the same memory. Why do you think you need a union instead of a struct?

Comment: People please. This is neither a typo nor not reproducable (apart from MRE issues). It is a misunderstanding of the hierarchies of compound datatypes which needs some explanation, e.g. in the shape of a counter-proposal which achieves what OP is obviously trying. (Yes I have an answer. Yes I want to save it. I admit.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swap your `union` with your `struct`.

I.e. I believe you want a union of a struct and an int, not a struct of a union and an int.
(I kept the now misleading name `myStruct_t`, which probably should be `myUnion_t` now.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t bit1 :1 ;
        uint8_t bit2 :1 ;
        uint8_t bit3 :1 ;
        uint8_t bit4 :1 ;
        uint8_t bit5 :1 ;
        uint8_t bit6 :1 ;
        uint8_t bit7 :1 ;
        uint8_t bit8 :1 ;
    }bits;
    uint8_t trial;
}myStruct_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    myStruct_t.trial=0; // use the encompassing union member for init
    myStruct_t.bits.bit1 = 1; // now use the bitwise view to set bits
    myStruct_t.bits.bit2 = 0;
    printf("%x",myStruct_t.trial);
    printf("%x",myStruct_t.bits.bit1);
    printf("%x",myStruct_t.bits.bit2);

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is 110, you might see 12810. Apart from the absent newlines, which would have helped, it means:

- the encompassing 8bit-view has a value of 1, at least with the endianess of my environment - you might see 128
- the bit 1 has a value of 1
- the bit 2 has a value of 0

Comment: By the way, no matter union or struct your `_t` is probably off. The name is not carried by a type, it is a global variable of an anonymous union type.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this reply is inspiring and satisfying.

Comment: My pleasure. :-)