# Accessing structure elements using a function without arguments

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading

I am trying to create a structure which should contain a byte and make accessing to it's bits easy. Target code supposed to work with my structure as follows:

```
    data8_t data;
    data = 7;
    unsigned char temp_data = data; 
    cout << "6th bit value = " << data.toBits().b6 << endl;
    data.toBits().b2 = 1;
```

However I cannot figure out how to code for the parts containing:

```
data.toBits().b6 
data.toBits().b2
```

How can I use an element identifier after calling a function without arguments which also belongs to the struct?

Variables to contain bit fields are specifically asked to be one byte long and my data8_t structure currently looks like this:

```
struct data8_t{
    uint8_t data;
    uint8_t b0;
    uint8_t b1;
    uint8_t b2;
    uint8_t b3;
    uint8_t b4;
    uint8_t b5;
    uint8_t b6;
    uint8_t b7;

data8_t(){
      b0=(data & 0x01)>>0;
      b1=(data & 0x02)>>1;
      b2=(data & 0x04)>>2;
      b3=(data & 0x08)>>3;
      b4=(data & 0x10)>>4;
      b5=(data & 0x20)>>5;
      b6=(data & 0x40)>>6;
      b7=(data & 0x80)>>7;
}

template <typename T>
    void operator=(T rhs){
        data = (uint8_t) rhs;
        b0=(data & 0x01)>>0;
        b1=(data & 0x02)>>1;
        b2=(data & 0x04)>>2;
        b3=(data & 0x08)>>3;
        b4=(data & 0x10)>>4;
        b5=(data & 0x20)>>5;
        b6=(data & 0x40)>>6;
        b7=(data & 0x80)>>7;
    }

    operator unsigned char() const{
        return (unsigned char) data;
    }
};
```

It is not elegant but it works for :

```
data = 7;
unsigned char temp_data = data;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bit Field Usage with Union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60196997/bit-field-usage-with-union)

Comment: If it is not an experiment, it is better for you to look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset. It does already what you need.

Comment: when you set the bits in constructor of struct, why didn't you call data.b2 and data.b6

Comment: `data8_t::toBits()` should return an object that has the bitwise members. You need to define that type.

Comment: I am aware this is all a bit out of the way but it is what is requested of me. If I could just figure out how to make `data.toBits().b6` work I would be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use c++ [bitfield](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field), it should do exactly what you want and will avoid duplicating the data.
You can implement it this way for example:

```
struct data8_t
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator=(T rhs) {
        data = (uint8_t)rhs;
    }
    union
    {
        uint8_t data;
        struct {
            uint8_t b0 : 1,
            b1 : 1,
            b2 : 1,
            b3 : 1,
            b4 : 1,
            b5 : 1,
            b6 : 1,
            b7 : 1;
        };
    };
};
```

Use it this way :

```
int main()
{
    data8_t b;
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        b = i;
        std::cout << (uint32_t)b.b0 << (uint32_t)b.b1 << (uint32_t)b.b2 << (uint32_t)b.b3 << (uint32_t)b.b4 << (uint32_t)b.b5 << (uint32_t)b.b6 << (uint32_t)b.b7 << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If you really want to have a function to access it I suppose you can do something like that :

```
struct data8_t
{
    struct bitfield
    {
        template <typename T>
        void operator=(T rhs) {
            data = (uint8_t)rhs;
        }

        operator unsigned char() const {
            return (unsigned char)data;
        }

        union
        {
            uint8_t data;
            struct
            {
                uint8_t b0 : 1,
                    b1 : 1,
                    b2 : 1,
                    b3 : 1,
                    b4 : 1,
                    b5 : 1,
                    b6 : 1,
                    b7 : 1;
            };
        };
    };

    template <typename T>
    void operator=(T rhs) {
        _data = (uint8_t)rhs;
    }

    operator unsigned char() const {
        return (unsigned char)_data;
    }

    bitfield& toBits() { return _data; }

private:
    bitfield _data;
};
```

**Edit - Make toBits work with the assignment operator bitwise**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is definitely better than my implementation. `bitfield toBits() { return bitfield(*this); }` does work for `cout << "6th bit value = " << data.toBits().b6 << endl;` but I am still trying to figure out how to make `data.toBits().b2 = 1;` work

Comment: I edited the second structure so it should be possible now as toBits returns a reference.